# GIT - Force manual merge for branch that would otherwise merge cleanly

Tags: git

I have the following situation

```
git branch
* master

git branch upgrade-project
git checkout upgrade-project

# At this point I run an update script from a third party that replaces 
# many files I have already modified.
git checkout master

# I want all conflicts to be marked regardless of weather GIT can merge them automatically.
git merge upgrade-project
```

The problem there is that it will cleanly merge all files replaced by the update-scripts from the upgrade-project branch as it is ahead of master which makes perfect sense in normal situations.

What I want is that when I merge `upgrade-project` into `master` all files that are in conflict are marked as such.

This was I can manually compare and make my modifications as needed.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the question? not clear to me. once you have conflicts they are displayed as ones

Comment: `upgrade-project` branch is ahead of the `master` branch.  Merging `upgrade-project` back into `master` would merge cleanly (no conflicts).  I would like to force conflicts for all files that are not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `upgrade-project` branch is ahead of `master`.
>   Merging `upgrade-project` back into `master` would merge cleanly (no conflicts).
>   I would like to force conflicts for all files that are not exactly the same

You can get a list of the files which are going to be pulled out before you execute the pull:

```
git checkout master
git diff --name-only upgrade-project
```

or:

```
git log --stat master ^upgrade-project
```

or

```
git format-patch master...upgrade-project
```

The last code sample will create a patch of each commit you have (diffrence between the branches which are going to be merged).

Comment: The `--no-commit` option did not work in my situation, I still can't see the GIT before and after `<<<<<` markers in the files.  It simply replaced the files with the ones that are ahead.

Comment: You can view the files in advance before teh pull if it will help you out

Comment: I have updated the answer according to your comments. read it now

Comment: Is there a way I can export the diffs to a file so I can relove after the merge?

Comment: You can use `git format-patch master...upgrade-project` but it will generate patch per commit that you have

Comment: Have you managed to create format-patch? ask me if you need more help on this

Comment: Yes, I have successfully created the patch.

Comment: Does it help you out? If so ill update the answer accordingly so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Merge your branch, but do not commit the changes:

```
git merge --no-commit upgrade-project
```

Clean the index, leaving the changes in working directory:

```
git reset
```

Resolve any conflict marked with `<<<<<` if any.

Interactivelly add the "good" changes you need to the index and commit them:

```
git add -p
git commit
```

Clean your working directory from unnecessary changes:

```
git reset --hard
```

Comment: Just tried this but it didn't work.  Just overrode all the files with the ones from `upgrade-project`

Comment: yes, because for git conflict is conflict only if it can not be resolved automatically. So you can merge postponing commit and clean up some changes from index with `git reset -p`.

Comment: not following, when should I run `git reset -p`?  After or before the merge and on which branch?

Comment: after `git merge --no-commit yourbranch`

Comment: I did that but it just prints out `No changes.`